# Setting focus on v-btn in a v-dialog that opens by default

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am attempting to set the focus on a v-btn inside a v-dialog that opens by default. (meaning the v-model is set to true. For the life of me I can not figure out how to do this.

I'm trying to do the following in my mounted, and it doesn't do anything at all.

```
    mounted() {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
      this.$refs.cancelTestDialog.$el.focus()
  })
},
```

My code pen is as follows.

https://codepen.io/jamiebrs/pen/rNwXddN

Comment: Can you focus a button ? `focus` is more like a method for input element.

Comment: Not from what I can tell. There has to be a way to set a focus on a v-btn

Answer (score 0):

For Vuetify 2 you have to use the following (I updated my codepen)

```
 setTimeout(() => {
        this.$refs.cancelTestDialog.$el.focus()
  })
```